# Can I get rid of the "learning bar"?

Tags: interface, version-10

I just purchased a home edition of Mathematica 10, and there seems to be a toolbar that I can't get rid of. It is kind of annoying and distracting. I couldn't find the option in the preference panel. Can someone kindly help?

[image]

Comment: I am glad you asked this. I was trying for sometime to find a way to remove it to get more space also. The banner on my version is even _larger_ than what you show. About 50% larger I would say

Comment: @Szabolcs fyi, I tried the option inspector method shown in that post you refer to, and it does not work. Can't edit the WindowFrame. Is there a way to do this in version 10, using optionInspector is the question

Comment: @Szabolcs: Me too. This seems not a duplication of that question because apparently Wolfram did something to prohibit this kind of modification.

Comment: @Nasser According to the comments, the firs answer there also doesn't work in v9 either. There are other answers for v9.  Have you tried the other methods?  (I cannot test this.)  Do any of them work?  I don't think there should be two questions on this, for organizational reasons.  One central location is much better.  The other question can be updated with v10 specific answers if necessary.

Comment: @Szabolcs I did not try the other method that changes files manually, as I was not sure I am allowed to. I'd rather see if I can change it in option inspector if possible first. It will not accept the change in OptionInspector, it stays stuck at "Normal", will not change to "Generic"

Comment: @Nasser Take a look at the comment thread under that answer to see why.  It seems it was causing problems.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Unfortunately, none of the answers in that question even works for me. The second answer needs the file `SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/MiscExpressions.tr` which doesn't exist in mathematica 10; the third answer modifies the `Docked Cells` which is already empty in MMA 10. Looks like wolfram integrated the panel into their interface (instead of a dock panel), the last two answers won't work for the same reason.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I might be ignorant here but I think it's ridiculous (and pointless) to add such a panel in a license that we've already paid hundreds for, and try so hard to prevent the user to change it. Is it there just to annoying us? This is such a hostility towards our hobbyist user.

Comment: @trVoldemort I just, it very much exists here (on OS X). Where are you looking?

Comment: @acl: I'm using Windows 8.1, where the the file should be at `C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources\MiscExpressions.tr`, but there's no folder called `TextResources` under `FrontEnd`.

Comment: maybe here: `FileNameJoin[
 Flatten[
  {$InstallationDirectory, 
   StringSplit["SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/", "/"]},
  1
  ]]`

Comment: @trVoldemort  I completely understand your frustration, I wouldn't like to have it either.

Comment: @trVoldemort I see, OK, no idea then. It must exist somewhere on your system, judging from its content.

Comment: @acl: Thank you so much for your second answer. I managed to find it here: `C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.0\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources`.